# Only the landing page load HTTPS all other pages I get The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, laravel, ssl, https, apache2

My site works fine on http but using https with a valid certificate will only load the landing page successfully. Trying to hit any other page results in URL not found.

I have a clone of the site on the same server with a different site name (test.mysite.com) working with a self-signed certificate on https. Not sure why one works and the other doesn't.

Apache conf files the are same (except site names).

Is it something with the cert file? I set up the self signed one but someone else set up the paid one.

Where do I look?

**/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000
```

~

**site.conf**

```
VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.ca
        ServerName  registration.mysite.ca


        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/registration.mysite.ca/public

        # SSL certs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/registration.mysite.ca.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/registration.mysite.ca.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 5242880
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/html/registration.mysite.ca/public/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSLEngine on` in `<VirtualHost *:80>` is pretty much useless because port 80 will never serve SSL content, so your certificate is definitely not used here.

You must have another `<VirtualHost *:443>` somewhere, potentially with a different `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: I editied my `sites.conf` to have a `<VirtualHost *:80> `  and an identical `<VirtualHost *:443>` right under it and that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you load css/js/images are you using src="http://registration.mysite.ca" ? If so change it to src="//registration.mysite.ca" and it should work.

Comment: That would still work with a few warnings. Plus, if the HTML pages and the assets are on the same domain, just ditch the domain from the paths. Smaller HTML and less prone to errors, plus you can change your domain without having to rewrite every single asset URL.

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged Laravel, I suggest using Laravel Forge to take care of everything like this. Big help for me. As for the question at hand, ensure that the virtual host is set to 443 and then force redirect all traffic to https.

Just add this into apache site config and change the domain. (note HTTPS)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```